# Python: how to build a dict from plain list of keys and values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of values like:

```
["a", 1, "b", 2, "c", 3]
```

and I would like to build such a dict from it:

```
{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
```

What is the natural way to do it in Python?

Comment: How did you get this list in the first place?  The loop which created that list **should** be fixed to create the dictionary directly.

Comment: @S.Lott: The list is the result of re.findall call

Comment: Please **update** the question with that important information.  It might help to should be original RE, also, since there may be ways to simplify your processing.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
>>> x = ["a", 1, "b", 2, "c", 3]
>>> i = iter(x)
>>> dict(zip(i, i))
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

Comment: @cha0site The left-to-right evaluation order of the iterables is guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks, this is the way! I even defined my list of items as x = (...) instead of [...] and got rid of explicit iter() call.

Comment: @Josh: It appears you are right, according to the [zip docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip). +1 then =)

Comment: @izhak The explicit `iter` call is needed to split the list in two. See the idiom at http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip

Comment: You could do it in one line: `dict(zip(*[iter(x)]*2))`

Comment: @IvoFlipse: Do you understand each component (iter, zip and dict)? Iter is simple: it'll just return the next value of the list when you call `.next()`. I've written a simple implementation of zip (that only works for two arguments): http://codepad.org/ywXjojYM

Try mentally replacing both left and right with `i` and run the code in your head, or alternatively add "prints" between each step.

Answer (score 14):

This seems rather succint, but I wouldn't call it very natural:

```
>>> l = ["a", 1, "b", 2, "c", 3]
>>> dict(zip(l[::2], l[1::2]))
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can `zip` the lists of alternate elements like so

```
>>> lst = ["a", 1, "b", 2, "c", 3]
>>> dict(zip(lst[::2], lst[1::2])
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
>>> l = ["a", 1, "b", 2, "c", 3]
>>> dict([l[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(l),2)])
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see many situations where you would run into this exact problem, so there is no 'natural' solution. A quick one liner that should do the trick for you would be however:

```
   {input_list[2*i]:input_list[2*i+1] for i in range(len(input_list)//2)}
```

Comment: I doubt that this will work. Also do not use builtin names (`input`) for variables. In Python 2.7 it simply fails on the for and in Python 3 it mourns about the argument for range being float.

Comment: Tried it in python 2.7.1 before posting. Not sure how it translates to other versions.

Comment: Look at http://ideone.com/K22Oa and http://ideone.com/XjKXl as well as http://ideone.com/Q2RS1

Comment: @Nobody: this works fine in 2.7; your ideone link is to 2.6, which doesn't have dict comprehensions.  Changing / to // would make it work in 3 as well.

Comment: @DSM Yes you are right, I memorized the python version of my system wrongly as being 2.7.1 (where it was 2.6.5) where I got the error. And as you can see in the third link I gave, I already devised the `//` correction. This discussion is another example why we always should give the version number when supplying python code.