# How to convert list items to dictionary key value pairs using comprehension

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list like this:

```
['1', "Santa's little helper", '4', 'Team', '6', 'Approximately 28.35 grams', '7', 'Breakfast that can be "everything"', '8', 'Was in first place']
```

How can I convert this into a dictionary using comprehension like this:

```
{'1': "Santa's little helper", '4': 'Team', ........}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: how to build a dict from plain list of keys and values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9485399/python-how-to-build-a-dict-from-plain-list-of-keys-and-values)

Comment: A comprehension won't work

Comment: @StopHarmingMonica you can use `{k: v for k, v in zip(myList[::2], myList[1::2])}`

Comment: @pault `zip` does all the work. At that point there's no reason not to use `dict`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `itertools.zip_longest()`:

```
d = dict(itertools.zip_longest(l[::2], l[1::2], fillvalue=''))
```

I don't think you can use a dict comprehension to do this, because a dict comprehension would involve every element. You could split the list in two and do a dict comprehension like this

```
my_dict = {x: y for x in my_list for y in my_list2}
```

but I think it's more effort than it's worth.

Edit: as @pault notes, the comprehension

```
{k: v for k, v in zip(myList[::2], myList[1::2])}
```

works too.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the list to generate list of tuple pairs (i, i+1) using **list comprehension**. Then can convert these to dictionary by calling `dict()`.

Example:

```py
d = dict([(your_list[i], your_list[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(your_list),2)])
```

Comment: This is not a comprehension.